# Qual versão do RadStudio que atulizou a biblioteca do TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi

Qual a versão do RadStudio que atualizou a biblioteca do TWebBrowser tornando-o compatível com as novas versões do Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme link da Embarcadero sobre as novas mudanças no RadStudio XE6, pode-se ver que é nessa versão que a atualização da biblioteca foi feita: **[What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C++Builder_XE6#Updates_to_TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE6#Updates_to_TWebBrowser)**

Citação:

> **Updates to [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser)**
>
> The web browser available on Windows ([SHDocVw.TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser)) has been updated to the latest version of Internet Explorer.